# Powershell Regular Expression for matching text with new lines

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to read the log files to check if the report has been sent to users successfully but I am running out of few issues with Powershell regular expression to search the content which has multiple lines.

---sample.txt

```
28/07/17 11:06.31: MailOut: To=test1@mail.com; Subject=PB Outstanding Training;
28/07/17 11:07.05: MailOut: To=test1@mail.com, test2@mail.com,
    test3@mail.com; From=mc@mail.com; Subject=NED Pending Training;
28/07/17 11:08.51: MailOut: To=test1@mail.com, 
    test2@mail.com, test3@mail.com, test4@mail.com, test5@mail.com, 
    test6@mail.com; From=mc@mail.com; Subject=PIR Number Sequencing;
```

In the above sample, I was able to match the required text since it lies on the same line but if the line is split into two or more then I am having difficulties.

---Here is my powershell script

```
$mailLogFile = Get-Content 'mail.log'
$mailLogFile -match "(28)/(07)/(\d+)(\s+)(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+):(\s+)(.+)PB Outstanding Training"
```

Above script worked fine for FIRST LINE OF THE "**sample.txt**". If I replace search string '**PB Outstanding Training**' with '**NED Pending Training**' it doesn't work for me.

I tried appending these characters before search string 
`(.\n)+(.\r+)(.\s+)(.t+)` but it didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated. Not sure what I am missing here

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content` returns a list of objects. You will have to loop through the collection and use your `-match` on each line.

MSDN has some info on `Get-Content` [MSDN Get-Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> The Get-Content cmdlet gets the content of the item at the location specified by the path, such as the text in a file. It reads the content one line at a time and returns a collection of objects, each of which represents a line of content.
>
> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, this cmdlet can also get a
>   specified number of lines from the beginning or end of an item.

Answer (score 0):

In your example above, I simply replaced "PB Outstanding Training" with "NED Pending Training"
Example:

```
 $mailLogFile -match "(28)/(07)/(\d+)(\s+)(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+):(\s+)(.+)NED Pending Training"
```

That seemed to work just fine.

Think I would go the select-string route though.
Example:

```
$MailLogFile | Select-String -Pattern "Ned Pending Training"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to output all lines that relevant to the searched subject.

```
@'
28/07/17 11:06.31: MailOut: To=test1@mail.com; Subject=PB Outstanding Training;
28/07/17 11:07.05: MailOut: To=test1@mail.com, test2@mail.com,
    test3@mail.com; From=mc@mail.com; Subject=NED Pending Training;
28/07/17 11:08.51: MailOut: To=test1@mail.com, 
    test2@mail.com, test3@mail.com, test4@mail.com, test5@mail.com, 
    test6@mail.com; From=mc@mail.com; Subject=PIR Number Sequencing;
'@ | Set-Content sample.txt
$lines = Get-Content sample.txt
$patdate = '28/07'
$patsubj = '(?:NED|PB)'
$s = ''
$lines | ForEach-Object {
  if( $_ -match "$patdate.+$patsubj" ) { $_; $s = '' }
  elseif( $_ -match "$patdate" ) { $s = $_ }
  elseif( $s -ne '' ) { 
    if( $_ -match "$patsubj" ) { "$s`n$_"; $s = '' }
    else { $s = "$s`n$_" }
  }
}
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##jZDdTsJAEIXv@xSTpkkh2kKp/KSkkaBgvBAa4R6XMkpNd4vdbTQBnr3uVipCgNirzsyZ75ydVfKJKV9iHOd5z9QanVq9XXPa4DhevWW7jgdPJIrHmfBgmvgCuXB6VHbsMKFdmGTzdwyFH/RBSrggbBGxN5imJGLyp3vIa9v15iXeNai6sa81kJ/quX88h2lCfRqeSDEa3EOAFyN07KZzOcKvZ@Mol3tU3xzVzVOQ1r@CB4/PMMroHFOY4EeGLCySmz3YyIaw7hImkAnghK5itMWX0Iw4YsjBh4cz8xURCyJQKsziAmbR4tJRtSq3nrzWJuhXZV9hTLNEbmCYpAMSLq1xkQ7W8jXRawWMGViUiHAJekm3r0qoDlVYS0kXdjjYyjWMOZ5Z3S0osZweiDlYDBVCKYpTnmDsTXWDvzBjph9a//BKi1JTjLbaNs@/AQ).